# Return array without name from method

Tags: java, arrays

I'm doing an assignment that requires me to complete the following block of code:

```
public int[] test(String input) {
    return new int[1];
}
```

I've already filled in part of it (I have to manipulate the string). But to return my results in the array, how should I do this? I don't see a clearly labeled array that I can write to; or can I create the array within the return line?

I could just be missing the point, and have to create my own array to replace the one given (just a thought).

Comment: It looks like the return line is in there just as a placeholder so it will compile. I doubt you are meant to use the one-element array as-is. You likely need to make your own array, fill it as the problem asks, and return that instead.

Comment: @jwd, my thoughts exactly, but I wanted to make sure there wasn't some advanced concept that I wasn't seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the constraints on the assignment? Would it be wrong to declare a local array, such as:

```
int[] i = new int[1];
/** Modify i as needed */
return i;
```

Then you could manipulate `i`.

If that's not allowed, then you can do something like:

```
return new int[] { /* int value(s) here, separated by commas */ };
```

Comment: I can't add my own instance variables, so your second suggestions might work.

Comment: @Jackie - Local variables are not instance variables. The former are local to the function whereas the latter belong to the each instance of the class.